# Unable to fetch particular commit hash from Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have updated manifest file with clone-depth=1 and when I try to do the repository sync I am getting the error below, our Gerrit config has all the required setting changes for shallow clone

```
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object
```

Gerrit config has the below settings in place

```
[uploadpack]

    allowTipSha1InWant = true
    allowReachableSHA1InWant = true
    allowAnySHA1InWant = true
```

any help on this